# How to get img src attribute from an ul of images?

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

```
<ul id="ulGall">
<li><img src="gaLL/red.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="gaLL/blue.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="gaLL/white.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="gaLL/orange.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 x = 0;
 z = $('#ulGall li').length;
});
```

.

```
$('#btnR').click(function() {
    if(x == z) {x = 1;} 
    else {x = x + 1;} // till here everything works  

    alert ($('ulGall').index =x, src attribute // just as description
```

i.e. - give me img `src` attribute - where `li index = x`

So first click should be `gaLL/red.jpg`
Next click - `gaLL/blue.jpg` and so on
After orange - red again.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness I added a jQuery alternative ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd offer an alternative, despite your having an already-accepted answer:

```
function clicks(el){
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var i = 0;
        clicks = function(el){
            var kids = $(el).find('img').length,
                which = i < kids ? i : i%kids;
            console.log($(el).find('img').eq(which).attr('src'));
            i++;
        };
        clicks(el);
    }
}

$('#ulGall').click(
    function(){
        clicks(this);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vumjz/).

And a slightly-revised, less-jQuery, function:

```
function clicks(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var i = 0;
        clicks = function(el) {

            var imgs = el.getElementsByTagName('img'),
                kids = imgs.length,
                which = i < kids ? i : i % kids;

            console.log(imgs[which].src);
            i++;
        };
        clicks(el);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vumjz/1/).

Comment: David, on accepted answer I get the alert `undefined`. Have you any idea ?

Comment: Post a link to a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) live demo, showing how you've coupled the answer to your own code and I'll see what I can do. I would suggest, though, that the better person to ask is the person who posted the code. Also, if that answer doesn't solve your problem it's not really a good idea to accept it as your answer (since it effectively misleads anyone who reads the question in future, and, frankly, *doesn't solve your problem*).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "src" attribute of the img inside the first li like this:

```
$("#ulGall li").eq(0).next("img").attr("src");
```

The number in the .eq() function determines which of the li elements is targeted - with the first having an index of 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnR').click(function() {
    if(x == z) {x = 1;} 
    else {x++}   
    var source=$("#ulGall li").eq(x).next("img").attr("src");
    alert(source);
});
```

The trick here is using .eq() which selects the element based on it's index, you can also select an element by index directly from the selector like so:

```
$("#ulGall li:eq(0)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector of jQuery.

```
$('#ulGall li:eq(0) img').attr('src')​
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, it seems that a good jQuery alternative is missing here.

```
$('button').each(function(){
    var idx = 0, $gallery = $("#ulGall").find("img");
    $(this).click(function(){
        var src = $gallery.eq(idx).attr("src");
        idx = (idx == $gallery.length - 1) ? 0 : idx + 1;
    });
});​
```

[A live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/EuvCD/)